# dplyr::mutate comparing each value to vector, collapsing with any/all

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset of true values (location) that I'm attempting to compare to a vector of estimated values using dplyr.  My code below results in an error message.  How do I compare each value of data$location to every value of est.locations and collapse the resulting vector to true if all comparisons are greater than 20?

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame("num" = 1:10, "location" = runif(10, 0, 1500) %>%   sort)
est.locations <- runif(12, 0, 1500) %>% sort

data %>% 
  mutate(false.neg = (all(abs(location - est.locations) > 20)))

   num  location false.neg
1    1  453.4281     FALSE
2    2  454.4260     FALSE
3    3  718.0420     FALSE
4    4  801.2217     FALSE
5    5  802.7981     FALSE
6    6  854.2148     FALSE
7    7  873.6085     FALSE
8    8  901.0217     FALSE
9    9 1032.8321     FALSE
10  10 1240.3547     FALSE
Warning message:
In c(...) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

The context of the question is dplyr, but I'm open to other suggestions that may be faster. This is a piece of a larger calculation I'm doing on birth-death mcmc chains for 3000 iterations * 200 datasets. (i.e. repeated many times and the number of locations will be different among datasets and for each iteration.)

UPDATE (10/13/15):

I'm going to mark akrun's solution as the answer.  A linear algebra approach is a natural fit for this problem and with a little tweaking this will work for calculating both FNR and FPR (FNR should need an (l)apply by iteration, FPR should be one large vector/matrix operation).

JohannesNE's solution points out the issue with my initial approach -- the use of any() reduces the number of rows to a single value, when instead I intended to do this operation row-wise.  Which also leads me to think there is likely a dplyr solution using rowwise() and do().

I attempted to limit the scope of the question in my initial post. But for added context, the full problem is on a Bayesian mixture model with an unknown number of components, where the components are defined by a 1D point process.  Estimation results in a 'random effects' chain similar in structure to the version of est.locations below.  The length mismatch is a result of having to estimate the number of components.

```
## Clarification of problem
options("max.print" = 100)
set.seed(1)

# True values (number of items and their location)
true.locations <- 
  data.frame("num"      = 1:10, 
             "location" = runif(10, 0, 1500) %>% sort)

# Mcmc chain of item-specific values ('random effects')
iteration <<- 0
est.locations <- 
  lapply(sample(10:14, 3000, replace=T), function(x) {
      iteration  <<- iteration + 1
      total.items <- rep(x, x)
      num         <- 1:x
      location    <- runif(x, 0, 1500) %>% sort
      data.frame(iteration, total.items, num, location)
    }) %>% do.call(rbind, .) 
print(est.locations)

      iteration total.items num      location
1             1          11   1   53.92243818
2             1          11   2  122.43662006
3             1          11   3  203.87297671
4             1          11   4  641.70211495
5             1          11   5  688.19477968
6             1          11   6 1055.40283048
7             1          11   7 1096.11595818
8             1          11   8 1210.26744065
9             1          11   9 1220.61185888
10            1          11  10 1362.16553219
11            1          11  11 1399.02227302
12            2          10   1  160.55916378
13            2          10   2  169.66834129
14            2          10   3  212.44257723
15            2          10   4  228.42561489
16            2          10   5  429.22830291
17            2          10   6  540.42659572
18            2          10   7  594.58339156
19            2          10   8  610.53964624
20            2          10   9  741.62600969
21            2          10  10  871.51458277
22            3          13   1   10.88957267
23            3          13   2   42.66629869
24            3          13   3  421.77297967
25            3          13   4  429.95036650
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 35847 rows ]
```

Comment: The nrow of data is not the same as length of est.locations.  If you want to do the comparisons, perhaps `apply(outer(df1$location, est.location, FUN= '-') > 20, 2, any)`

Comment: `est.locations <- runif(12, 0, 1500) %>% sort`should be `10` instead `12`

Comment: The number of 'true' values are frequently different than the number 'estimated' values.  The comparison is the difference between each value of data$location and all values of est.location -- if any are TRUE, then the result should be a single value = TRUE.

Comment: Do you really want to force this recycling with a length mismatch between location and est.locations? It seems like a mistake. @Mateusz1981 seems right that your `runif(n...)` length parameters mismatch.

Comment: I'm trying to do 10, 1 by 12 comparisons that each reduce to one result with the use of 'all' (for a total of 10 values, one per row of 'data'). I'll clarify a bit more on the morning.

Comment: I think Akrun's right, that it's best solved with matrix algebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `outer` for this kind of comparison.  We get all the combination of difference between 'location' and 'est.locations', take the `abs`, compare with 20, negate (`!`), do the `rowSums` and negate again so that if all the elements in the rows are greater than 20, it will be TRUE.

```
data$false.neg <- !rowSums(!abs(outer(data$location, est.locations, FUN='-'))>20)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use sapply (here inside mutate, but not really taking advantage of its functions).

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame("num" = 1:10, "location" = runif(10, 0, 1500) %>%   sort)
est.locations <- runif(12, 0, 1500) %>% sort

data %>% 
    mutate(false.neg = sapply(location, function(x) {
        all(abs(x - est.locations) > 20)
    }))

   num   location false.neg
1    1   92.67941      TRUE
2    2  302.52290     FALSE
3    3  398.26299      TRUE
4    4  558.18585     FALSE
5    5  859.28005      TRUE
6    6  943.67107      TRUE
7    7  991.19669      TRUE
8    8 1347.58453      TRUE
9    9 1362.31168      TRUE
10  10 1417.01290     FALSE
```